# Using instead of trigger to convert data types

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with a bigint column that I'm attempting to get an insert working for. We've been having issues where data that can't be converted to a numeric comes in and the insert fails. This is mostly things like spaces or line returns in the data i.e. " 123", "1 365".

Since I don't have access to the software that is attempting to insert this bad data, I thought that creating an instead of trigger and using a function to strip out all non-numeric characters would fix the issue.

This is a basic idea of what the trigger is doing.

```
TRIGGER [dbo].[Delivery_Before_TRG] 
   ON  [dbo].[Delivery]
   instead of INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Delivery]
           (....,[pin],....)
    select ....
           ,[dbo].[udf_GetNumericOnly](inserted.pin)
           ,....
    from inserted;

END
```

And this is the udf_GetNumberOnly function.

```
FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetNumericOnly]
(
    @Value varchar(500)
)
RETURNS bigint
AS

BEGIN

    Declare 
        @Pos tinyint,
        @Char char(1)

    Set @Value = REPLACE(@Value, ' ', '')       -- Strip all spaces
    Set @Pos = LEN(@Value)                      -- Give some non-zero value
    While @Pos > 0
        Begin
            Set @Pos = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @Value)     )
            If @Pos > 0 
                Begin
                    Set @Char = SUBSTRING(@Value, @Pos, 1)      -- Non numeric character
                    Set @Value = REPLACE(@Value, @Char, '')
                End
        End

    Set @Value = RTrim(LTrim(@Value))

    Return convert(bigint,@Value)

END
```

I can run the function and it will strip all non-numeric characters for anything that I pass it, however, when I attempt to run an insert statement into my table I get a *Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 4
Error converting data type varchar to bigint.* error.

From what I can tell the problem is something to do with sql server checking that the fields I'm attempting to to insert match the destination table column datatypes before my trigger gets a hold of the data to convert it. I know this because I had modified the trigger to insert a number directly into the pin field and would still get this error.

Additionally, I know it isn't the function failing because I can write an insert that will fail and then change that insert to call the function, and it will work.

```
--This fails
INSERT INTO (....,pin,...)
VALUES(....,'1a23',....)

--This works
INSERT INTO (....,pin,...)
VALUES(....,udf_GetNumericOnly('1a23'),....)
```

Comment: What year version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I believe we're on SQL Server 2012. It's version 11.0.2100.60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, the algebrizer looks at the data types in your query right after the parser makes sure you've written valid sql. The INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger fires for each row that would be inserted, which an invalid cast wouldn't be.

Comment: So I'm assuming this would mean that there is no way around this and my only options would be to change the data type for that column to varchar, or somehow get the insert to always be "cast-able".

Comment: It sounds like you can't change the application, but the farther upstream the data is clean, the better. You could do some ugly stuff like changing the column to varchar like you mention and maybe have a SQL Agent job run once every so often to remove non # characters? The real solution is at the source though. :)